# I am trying to get the assembly folder path

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the below code to get the path:

```
 string componentName =System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

It returns the complete path:

> C:\PurgeEngineIntegrated\PurgeEngine\PurgeEngine\bin\Debug

But I wanted to go to the path:

> C:\PurgeEngineIntegrated\PurgeEngine\PurgeEngine\GDPR Files

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to "go to" that path? Is it always located in such a way that it is relative to the current path "..\..\GDPR Files" or do you have any requirements for that? Why are you not using for instance AppData or ProgramData for your data instead of a relative path to the executing path?

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct.  It is returning the location from which your assembly is running.  When Visual Studio compiles, that is the folder that it is put into.  If GDPR Files is a folder that should be present with the run time, you can either mark it as Copy Always or Copy Only If Newer. Alternatively, you need to manually copy that folder over.

Comment: it would also work if i get the complete path before bin folder:C:\PurgeEngineIntegrated\PurgeEngine\PurgeEngine, but i dont want to hardcode and delete that path.

Comment: Yes and no.  It would work with Visual Studio, but any published project tends not to have a BIN folder.  Thus, you have a design choice to make.  Either 1 - specify a configuration variable that holds the actual path to the GDPR folder, 2 - make a function to work out the path and decide if you need to mangle the location, 3 - make the solution create/copy the folder when building or 4 - manually do that.and have an installer copy that folder in when installing your software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string componentName = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + "\\GDPR Files";
```

Please note `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` this will give you the working directory path which is `C:\PurgeEngineIntegrated\PurgeEngine\PurgeEngine\bin\Debug` and this code `Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName` will give you the path before the `Bin` folder. If you run the program from `exe` file from the `Debug` folder, it will still work as it gives you the path of two steps up of the current location. So you have to be careful if you want to use it in different location.

Comment: Whilst this would work with Visual Studio and the source project present, it wouldn't work in the live environment unless the GDPR Files folder was always at a higher level.

Answer (score -1):

You can try **UriBuilder.UnescapeDataString()** to get directory from assembly location

```
    string componentName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    UriBuilder oUriBuilder = new UriBuilder(componentName);
    string strPath = oUriBuilder.UnescapeDataString(oUriBuilder.Path);
    string strDirectory =  Path.GetDirectoryName(strPath);
```